# Como inserir um valor de uma variável no Header do PHP?

Tags: php, header

Minha intenção é que na hora que excluir um nota fiscal, ele volte para página de índice de notas referente aquela obra.

Código:

```
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $ok = $_GET['obra'];
    //Delete do banco:
    $pdo = Banco::conectar();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM notas where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    Banco::desconectar();
    header('Location: index01.php?obra=' . $ok); 
}
```

Comment: A forma de concatenar os valores está correta. Há algum problema ao executá-lo?

Comment: apesar de eu estar testando a variável e ela tá aparecendo valor, neste header não está, ele volta para a página sem valor! então eu não sei ao certo oq está acontecendo!